# Is there any reference connecting the Serpent in the Garden with rebellious divine beings?

Tags: angels, eden, throne-of-god, elohim, divine-counsel

Three references in scripture force my re-examination of the role of serpents/reptiles in scripture:

1. The brazen serpent (Nehushtan) raised up by Moses and it's connection to Christ (John 3:14)
2. YeShua's commandment to be wise as serpents
3. Seraphim etymologically related to "shining/serpent"

These points suggest these other world beings do not fit into perfectly into the good/evil dualistic paradigm.

Comment: I am voting to close because this question lacks details or clarity. This is because your title talks of "serpent IN THE GARDEN" but your three examples have nothing to do with the garden. So is the question about the garden or is it just a generic question about serpents? Moreover your assumption that there is a "good/evil dualistic paradigm" seems a bit biased and unbiblical. The bible is not Zoroastrian, and that's a distraction. So as it stands, you have the title, the first paragraph, and the last paragraph, with little connection between any of the three sections - a confusing question